# Identify novel about Jesus reincarnated as a girl

Tags: story-identification

A cloned "daughter" of a scientist realizes she is reincarnated Jesus. I remember it as a really quick, interesting read.

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like *[Only Begotten Daughter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_Begotten_Daughter)* by James Morrow.

> The story is about Julie Katz, the new Messiah, who is the daughter of God, and who is spontaneously conceived from a sperm bank donation by her father, Murray Katz, through "inverse parthenogenesis". Julie struggles with her messianic powers, the mind games of Satan, being hunted by fundamentalists, and the silence of her mother, God.